# How to process command line arguments?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

Yesterday I made a simple program in c++ that uses the arguments passed through command line.

```
E.G. myDrive:\myPath\myProgram.exe firstWord secondWord
```

The program run fine and do what it has to, but there's a little curiosity I have:
I had to write `argc --;` before I could use it well, otherwise I have a run-time crash [The compiler won't speak!].

In particular `argc` gives me a bad time when I don't give any word as argument to the program when I run it...

Now it works, so isn't bad at all, but I wonder why this is happening!
[P.S. making `argc --;` and printing it, it gives `0` as value!]

EDIT:
Here all the istructions that use `argc`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    [...]
    argc --;
    if(argc > 0){
        if(firstArg.find_last_of(".txt") != string::npos){
            reading.open(argv[1], ios::binary);
            [...]
        }
    }
    if ((!(firstArg.find_last_of(".txt") != string::npos)) && argc > 0){
    [...]
        for(int i = 1; i <= argc; i ++){
        [...]
        toTranslate = argv[i][j];
        [...]
        toTranslate = argv[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I'm sure you've written something like `i<=argc`. Show us the code by the way.

Comment: I edit the answer, give me a sec!

Comment: are you under linux? [`getopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt)?

Comment: I am under Windows 8!

Comment: How do you define `toTranslate`? It has to be `char`.

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry, I didn't write it!
`toTranslate` is char and `reading` is ifstream!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments *include* the name of the program itself as well, so `argc` is always at least 1.

Here's the typical loop:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i != argc; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Argument #" << i << ": " << argv[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can print backwards:

```
while (argc--)
{
    std::cout << argv[argc] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Yup, but the probram crash even if I try to print argc with `cout << argc`, and it only crashes if I do it before i minus it!

Comment: @IngrossoD: Just use `i < argc` instead of `i <= argc` in your posted  code. **And** don't do `argc--` in the begining!

Comment: @Nawaz: It takes crash before the for loop!
I started as you said!

Comment: @IngrossoD: In that case, then **comment everything** and then do **only** `cout << argc`. See if it crashes now. It doesn't, then uncomment one (or two) statement at a time, then compile and run each time. See exactly which line causes the crash!

Comment: Thanks friend, it was the assignment on `string firstArg` that I have [badly] omitted in the question!
Also, using Kerrek method it's all fine [;